# How to solve following without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve this without using a calculator?

> $$\color{blue}{\sin\left(x+y\right)},$$
>
> $$
>   \text{given}
>     \quad
>   \cos x=\frac45
>     \quad
>   \text{and}
>     \quad
>   \sin y= \frac{\sqrt 2}{10}.
> $$

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before functions like sin, you get the proper font and spacing.  So \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of $sinx$

Comment: Considering that both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(y)$ could be negative, there is more than one possible value for $\sin(x+y)$. Assuming both $x$ and $y$ lie in the first quadrant gives one such possible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $0\leq x,y \leq \pi/2$,

$$\cos(x)=4/5\Rightarrow \sin(x)=3/5$$ and

$$\sin(y)=\sqrt{2}/10\Rightarrow \cos(y)=7\sqrt{2}/10$$

then from the identity and putting the values in place

$$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)=\sqrt{2}/2$$

Comment: It's not known that either $x$ or $y$ is in the first quadrant.

Comment: right, I assumed $0\leq x,y \leq \pi/2$, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: MathJax hint:  If you enclose the stuff you want to take the square root of in braces, the square root sign extends to cover them.  So \sqrt {123} gives $\sqrt {123}$ instead of \sqrt 123 which gives $\sqrt 123$.  This works with multicharacter exponents, subscripts, etc. as well. There is no need if you just want one character under the square root sign

Answer (score 4):

Without further information we can assume $x,y$ in the first quadrant

$\implies\sin x=+\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=\cdots$

and $\cos y=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}=\cdots$

Now use $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$

Answer (score 2):

By $\cos^2u+\sin^2u=1,$

$$\sin x=\pm\frac35,\\\cos y=\pm\frac{7}{10}\sqrt2.$$

The possible solutions are

$$\frac{\pm3\cdot7\sqrt2+4\sqrt2}{50}=\frac{\sqrt2}2\text{ or }-\frac{17}{50}\sqrt2.$$